# Rewrite url in Silex PHP Framework

Tags: url-rewriting, silex

I am new in Silex Framework and I have a problem with url rewriting.

Question :

When I type this in browser -> `http://localhost/mysite/` It is working and it loads index view.

```
$app->get('/', function() use($app) {

    return $app['twig']->render('index.twig.html');

});
```

But when I type `http://localhost/mysite/about`

```
$app->get('/about', function() use($app) 
{ 
    return $app['twig']->render('about.twig.html');
});
```

It gives me following error : `The requested URL http://localhost/mysite/about was not found on this server.`

If I type this url `http://localhost/mysite/index.php/about`

This url is working, I don't understand why? I need load this view without this index.php in the url. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use this as the contents of your `.htaccess` file (based on the one provided by the Symfony Standard Edition).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying but it gives me the same error "Not Found

The requested URL /mysite/about was not found on this server."

Comment: I think .htaccess is not working there is no changes any content of .htaccess May be requires some changes in apache config?

Comment: It's likely that either the apache rewrite module is not enabled, or .htaccess files are not permitted (i.e. `AllowOverride All` is not set in the main Apache config)

Answer (score 1):

You are using Silex in a subdirectory:

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php/about
```

therefore you have to adjust the RewriteBase of your .htaccess, try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /mysite
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If your server is running Apache >= 2.2.16 you can use the the FallbackResource instead of the above code, try this single line:

```
FallbackResource /mysite/index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in rewrite_mode in Apache. I changed Apache default config -> " AllowOverride All "

`http://www.jarrodoberto.com/articles/2011/11/enabling-mod-rewrite-on-ubuntu`

And I added .htaccess file. It is working, thanks for everybody!